# Installing apple root certificates is not allowed on the App Store

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, app-store

Apple review team has rejected my app with with the following message: "Your app installs root certificates for unapproved purposes, which is not allowed on the App Store".

I installed the certificate based on the guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2.

Listing 1-4 prescribes to load the certificate to check that the receipt is signed by Apple.

As far as I understand - if I remove the certificate then everyone will be able to generate the receipt.

How could I obtain the necessary approval for that purpose ?

**Edit:** I just added file "AppleIncRootCertificate.cer" to the bundle.
And then loaded it:

```
    NSData *rootCertData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@(ddd) withExtension:@"cer"]];
    const uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)(rootCertData.bytes);
    X509 *appleCA = d2i_X509(NULL, &data, (long)rootCertData.length);
    if (appleCA) {
        BIO *payload = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        X509_STORE_add_cert(store, appleCA);
        if (payload) {
            verifyReturnValue = PKCS7_verify(p7,NULL,store,NULL,payload,0);
            BIO_free(payload);
        }
        X509_free(appleCA);
   }
```

Another point from the Apple team is that I should turn off "iTunes file sharing". Could it relate to their concern with certificate ?

Comment: If you think the app store review has treated you unfairly, file an appeal. They'll phone you and you can talk it over.

Comment: The guide says you need to “load the root certificate”, not install it into the system keychain. Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: I requested Apple team. They asked to turn-off "iTunes sharing". Probably it relates to installing certificates. I did that and they approved the application. I didn't remove certificate